# Why does jQuery still detect an element as visible when it is set to display:none?

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery to loop through a `sortable` list and detect each `list` item that is visible.

Elements are added to the list from a database query on page load. They are hidden using `.hide()`.
They can be set as visible from a button using `.show()` to 'add' them to the list.

**I would like to extract the list state, as visible to the user by detecting which are visible.**

When I use the `:visible` selector the items set as `display:none` are still being picked up. According to the `:visible` documentation items are only detected when they take up space on the page, which these don't.

[FIDDLE here, item 5 is set as display:none](http://jsfiddle.net/3PeMS/)

***Constructive criticism rather than downvotes please.***

Comment: `$('#sortable li').is(':visible')` returns `true` if  **at least one of all** `<li>`s is visible. Trivially true (fix by looping through the `<li>`s instead of the `#sortable`, and use `$(this).is(':visible')`: http://jsfiddle.net/3PeMS/1/).

Comment: Why don't you loop through visible `li` elements? http://jsfiddle.net/3PeMS/2/

Comment: Hey great. I prefer not to use $(this) as it will allow different tag types when maybe it would be better to throw an error. It works though. Can you make this an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @m.spyratos You left the .each() on a unique ID, and continued to use .is() where .filter() would be better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the answer is in a fiddle, this is essentially what Rob W suggested:

```
//On button Click
$(".updateDetailsButton").click(function () {
    //Loop through each visible item in the sortable list
    $("#sortable li:visible").each(function(index) {
         // ...
    });
});
```